# LEFT JOIN to find sum of two columns in different tables

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have the following query where I am trying to get a total number of goals and total number of votes for a player over a career.

```
SELECT
    p.PlayerID,
    SUM(s.votes) AS Votes,
    SUM(p.Goals) AS TotalGoals
FROM
    PlayerDetails p
LEFT JOIN PlayerVotes s ON
    p.PlayerID = s.PlayerID AND p.Season = s.Season
WHERE
    p.PlayerID = $PlayerID


PlayerDetails table
PlayerID | Season | Round | Goals |

PlayerVotes table
PlayerID | Season | Votes |
```

The main difference in the data in the tables is the PlayerDetails table has player data for a season over a number of rows - for example Fred Smith plays 10 games so has a row for each game comprising PlayerID, Season, Round and Goals scored.  The PlayerVotes table has one row for each player per season with the total votes for that season.  For example in 2017 Fred Smith received 10 votes, so there would be one row of data PlayerID, Season and Votes.

The query is returning the sum of goals for the player over the career but the sum of votes is no where near correct.

I've tried removing the AND "p.Season = s.Season" on the join, but that doubles the goal and votes tallies.

If I run this basic query on my PlayerVotes table the result is as expected

```
SELECT PlayerID, SUM(Votes) 
FROM PlayerVotes 
WHERE PlayerID = $PlayerID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a script like this:

```
SELECT p.PlayerID, SUM(p.Goals) AS Goals, pv.Votes FROM PlayerDetails AS p
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT SUM(ppv.Votes) AS Votes, ppv.PlayerID, ppv.Season FROM PlayerVotes AS ppv
     GROUP BY ppv.PlayerID, ppv.Season 
) AS pv ON pv.PlayerID = p.PlayerID AND pv.Season = p.Season
WHERE p.PlayerID = $PlayerID;
```

Comment: I tried that, whilst it returns the SUM of the goals, it returns only the votes received for the first season - ie Fred Smith got 5 votes in 2017 and 10 votes in 2018 - this just returns SUM of votes as '5' when it should return '15'

Comment: I removed the season group by and it works - thanks igor

Comment: You are welcome, if this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider accepting it as correct one so it will help others as well in the future :)

Comment: My next step is, I have a team column also on both tables, so if a player switches teams form one year to the next - I also need the tallies to be grouped by team too - I'll see if I can work that out next

Comment: ok, so I've been trying to include the Team (Team is a common column in both tables) so the query breaks down per team by adding a GROUP BY pv.Team at the end of the query - whilst this correctly splits the player votes by team into separate rows, in the instance of a player who has played in two or more teams the team and goals totals on each row are for one team only.  Here's an example on my site to show the output (Note there are more columns than just the goals)  http://waflfootyfacts.net/player/stats1.php?PlayerID=4809

Comment: SELECT
    p.PlayerID,
    p.Team,
    SUM(p.Goals) AS Goals,
    pv.Votes,
    COUNT(*) AS SeasonP,
    SUM(p.Goals) AS G
FROM
    PlayerDetails AS p
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT SUM(ppv.Votes) AS Votes,
        ppv.PlayerID,
        ppv.Season,
        ppv.Team
    FROM
        Sandover AS ppv
    GROUP BY
        ppv.PlayerID,
        ppv.Team
) AS pv
ON
    pv.PlayerID = p.PlayerID
WHERE
    p.PlayerID = $PlayerID
GROUP BY
        pv.Team

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your current problem. You said that the group by TEAM worked but the result is not what you expected ?

Comment: The GROUP BY Team worked for calculating the PlayerVotes but not for the goals (and other stats) - if you take a look at the sample link in my comments above you can see the total for the votes is correct (160 & 69) but all the other totals displayed are the sub total for Peel Thunder when it should show a row for East Fremantle and the totals for the players games for that club as well - does that help?

Comment: Well in order to get the same type of total for the other rows, you will need to modify the query so that all the SUM values are returned like the Votes are. So you will most likely need LEFT JOIN ( SELECT SUM(fiel) ) for all of them.

Comment: Coming back to this as I haven't been able to solve this - Can someone explain how I can do what Igor suggested - I can't seem to work out how to LEFT JOIN Sum the other fields